# How can I upload TeamCity's artifacts folder into an AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, teamcity

I'm using S3 to host a static website and want to be able upload the result of a TeamCity's build into the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 5):

After working on this for a while, found a solution.

Having TeamCity Agent hosted in an EC2 instance launched using an IAM Role in AWS.

Setup a deployer IAM Role with access to the S3 bucket and allowing TeamCity IAM Role to assume it.

Then use AWS CLI commands to upload content to the bucket.

**Example (Powershell)**

STEP 1. Request temporary credentials for the account

```
#-----------------------------
# Get parameters
#-----------------------------
$RoleArn = "%param_deployer_arn%"
$ExternalId = "%param_assume_role_external_id%"
$Region = "%param_region%"
$SessionName = "%param_session_name%"

#-----------------------------
# AWS Authentication - Assume Role
#-----------------------------
$Response = (Use-STSRole -Region $Region -RoleArn $RoleArn -ExternalId $ExternalId -RoleSessionName $SessionName).Credentials
$SecretAccessKey = $Response.SecretAccessKey
$SessionToken = $Response.SessionToken
$AccessKeyId = $Response.AccessKeyId

#-----------------------------
# Set environment variables
#-----------------------------
"##teamcity[setParameter name='env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY' value='$SecretAccessKey']"
"##teamcity[setParameter name='env.AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN' value='$SessionToken']"
"##teamcity[setParameter name='env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID' value='$AccessKeyId']"
```

STEP 2. (Access AWS using session token and access key stored in environment variables)

IMPORTANT: needs to be done in different step in TeamCity)

```
#-----------------------------
# List S3 bucket content
#-----------------------------
aws s3 ls s3://%S3Bucket%
```

Comment: can you please show how you did the CLI step on TeamCity?

Answer (score 4):

There is third party plugin: https://github.com/guardian/teamcity-s3-plugin

Also I would recommend watching for this request in TeamCity tracker as at some point there can be official support: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-21560

Comment: As an outcome of the linked issue there is also an officially developed plugin by Jetbrains https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-s3-artifact-storage-plugin.